# File browser delete

Tags: export, import

Is it possible to delete files within blender itself? (folders, images etc)

I see it on youtube videos and i wanna know if that is possible (I hope not)

Comment: Do you mean if you can delete other files not familiar with a blender from the blender File view? Of course, you can, you can create new folders and delete as well(folders and files). Or do you mean remove images from Blender that you inserted in Blender before?

Comment: Delete files in fileview I mean to Say. In gimp user cannot delete folders in fileview but why users can remove files in blender?

Comment: Yes you can, just use your right mouse button and you will see the option to Delete selected files, shortcut is the key X

Comment: I'm worried because maybe I deleted the wrong files or folder where my family pictures are there.

Comment: Well, that can easily happen, that's why you should always take care be cautions or backup files

Comment: Will it come to the bin in windows or it will direct deleted?

Comment: Moves it to the recycle bin (at least under Windows).

Comment: If not would look into other methods of file recovery for your OS ASAP.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers